# Help with Artorias

Tags: dark-souls

I'm having trouble with the Artorias fight in the Dark Souls DLC. I have been trying with all combinations of weapons and armour, but nothing seems to even bring his HP down to 1/3.

Are there any tips or vulnerabilities about Knight Artorias that I should keep in mind?

Comment: Try to summon help. Sunbros are there for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some strategies I used recently:

- **Stop Artorias from powering up.** This is what he is doing when he backs away and kneels. The best way I found to reliably stop this is by **shooting him in the head with an arrow**. You can also run up and hit him, but it takes several hits to stop the power up (depending on your weapon) and you risk being hit by the AoE explosion if you fail to stagger him. Arrows are much safer, though aiming can be difficult. Practice.
- **Know when you can get in a hit.** I never tried hitting him while doing his forward somersault attack, since he doesn't give you time to recover and raise your shield if you get hit by one of the successive attacks.
- **Don't get greedy.** Hit once, back away and recharge your stamina.
- **Use a shield with high stability.**
- **Try to keep your stamina bar full.** Especially when you're expecting his attack. This means: attack once, back away, lower shield to regen stamina, shield up.

If you don't manage to stop Artorias from powering up (for example, if you needed the break to heal) you need to be extra careful since his attacks drain more stamina when they hit your shield and do much more damage. Block as much as you can and wait for his power up to run out.

Also, I found using a spear to be helpful, since it's much more forgiving if you attack at the wrong time (as you can still block while you attack).

Good luck!

Comment: In addition: if he manages to power up, you can just wait a bit and his buff will go away. If you damage him too quickly, he can buff himself multiple times.